# How to build a 2D numpy array from 3 vectors (X ,Y and Z) where A[X,Y] += Z?

Tags: numpy-ndarray

I want to create a 2D numpy array from 3 same size vectors, taking 2 of them as indeces of each dimension and the third one as assigned value, ADDING it to the saved one in the same position. I built the array of zeros first, then assigning the value as A[X,Y] +=Z. For example:

```
import numpy as np

X = [0,1,1]

Y = [2,2,2]

Z = [1,2,3]

A = np.zeros([3, 3], dtype=int8)

A[X,Y] +=Z
```

The result:

```
A = array([[0, 0, 1],
           [0, 0, 3],
           [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

I was expecting A[1,2] = 5 (A[X1,Y1] + A[X2,Y2] = 2+3), but actually A[1,2] = 3 (just the last value was hold). How can I solve this problem in a numpy way?

I get the Python style solution but it is slower

```
for i,j,k in zip (X,Y,Z):
    A[i,j]+= k

print (A)

A = array([[0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `np.add.at` ufunc like this:

```py
import numpy as np

X = [0, 1, 1]
Y = [2, 2, 2]
Z = [1, 2, 3]

A = np.zeros((3, 3))

np.add.at(A, (X, Y), Z) # Has to be tuple, or it won't work

print(A)
```

Output:

```py
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 5.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: thank you very much Naphat Amundsen, solved

Comment: No problem! It would be nice if you could mark my answer as the solution as well.